# Error with data type of List in a list with str and int

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

I am having problems with the type of data of a function I am writing. The data being inputted is a list with a list of str and int. It looks like this:

```
list_example = [['a', 1],['b', 2],['c', 3]]
```

The function looks like this:

```
def inputting_incrementing(club: str, list: List[List[str, int]]) -> None:
```

The error is this:

> TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got [class
>   'str', class 'int']

Anyone can shed some light on this problem? Anything helps.

Comment: The type annotation says tuple but you gave it a list. I don't see how that will work. Also, the variable `list` overwrites a builtin function--don't do this.

Comment: Are you importing `from typing import List, Tuple` ? What Python version are you using? Cannot reproduce

Comment: what version of Python are you running? In any case that error message implies you did something like `str = 'foo'` and `int = 42`, and then tried to use those variables as arguments to the typing object `Tuple`. In any case, you *have* to provide a [mcve].

Comment: made a little mistake, says List instead of tuple. The version is python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your error. The error you get is what you'd get if you'd entered:

```
List[[str, int]]
```

Did you perhaps name a global variable `List` or `Tuple` in such a way that "indexing" it would result in code that evaluated to the above? I suggest this because you're clearly not being careful about variable names (you named the parameter `list`, shadowing the `list` constructor for the body of that function).

I suggest adding a `print(List, Tuple)` to ensure they're still the types from the `typing` module, and making sure you haven't accidentally doubled the brackets somewhere, as in my example above.

I'll also note that even if this works, the annotation doesn't match the input you're providing; you're providing a `list` of `list`s, not a `list` of `tuple`s.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, but it is supposed to be List, not Tuple. The goal of the function is to be able to input a nested list of lists. I printed the types of List and Tuple and they resulted in the correct output, being the same types from the typing.

Comment: Unfortunately, `List[str, int]` is illegal; `typing.List` only supports the intended use case for `list`s, which is a variable length, homogeneous sequence, which means `List` can only take one parameter. If you want to misuse it like this, the closest to a legal annotation you can get is `List[List[Any]]` or `List[List[Union[str, int]]]`, but neither one will enforce the inner `list`s being exactly two elements long, with a `str` followed by an `int`. `Tuple` can be used for either fixed-length heterogeneous `tuple`s (the primary use) or for "immutable lists", but `List` isn't that flexible.

Comment: @AntonyD: In any event, neither `List[Tuple[str, int]]` nor `List[List[str, int]]` would produce the error you describe, so your error is coming from somewhere else. We need a [MCVE] to help, and you've provided an example, but not a complete or reproducible one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way to create a tuple is by placing all the elements between parentheses. If you want to create a list of tuples you should do it like this:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1)]
```